# How to rename all files in a directory

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a directory containing about 200 mp3 files. They are strangely numbered, such that during playing they are executed in a rather unpredictable order. That is how few of them are called to give a short example:

```
lst1 = 
  {"01_04_49.mp3", "01_04_50.mp3", "01_04_51.mp3", "02_01_01.mp3",
   "02_01_02.mp3", "02_01_03.mp3"}
```

I would like to rename them using Mathematica into something like

```
lst2 = {"1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3", "4.mp3", "5.mp3", "6.mp3"}
```

in the same order as they appear in the list above.

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: So, `lst1` is already in the desired order? Assuming that, try `MapIndexed[RenameFile[#1, IntegerString[#2[[1]]] <> ".mp3"] &, lst1]`.

Comment: @ J. M.Thank you.Could you please kindly comment, how Mma will understand, in which directory to rename the files?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch do you have the directory on hand? Just use a FileNameJoin on both parts then. Alternatively look at FileSystemMap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SystemDialogInput` to choose the path at run time. Expanding on J.M.'s comment, you could evaluate something like this:

```
Module[{names, path},
  names = 
    {"01_04_49.mp3", "01_04_50.mp3", "01_04_51.mp3", 
     "02_01_01.mp3", "02_01_02.mp3", "02_01_03.mp3"}; 
  path = SystemDialogInput["Directory", WindowTitle -> "Choose a folder"];
  If[path === $Canceled,
  $Canceled,
  SetDirectory[path];
  MapIndexed[RenameFile[#1, IntegerString[#2[[1]]] <> ".mp3"] &, names];
  SetDirectory[]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.